# Query On MDX query through Enterprise gateway in Power Bi

Tags: ssas, powerbi

I have a MDX query which i want to use as dataset in PowerBI application, I have published MDX Query data through Power BI Desktop Application.

Now, I want to set "schedule Refresh" but this need to be connect with some gateway. My system is having installed Enterprise Gateway.

Now, I am not able to set this and showing me personal gateway in "Scheudle Refresh" which is already selected and do not have any option to change this.

My Question: Why it is connected with personal Gateway, even my system is only having a Enterprise gateway?
And How can i change the gateway setting from personal gateway to Enterprise Gateway for my MDX dataaset.

Comment: have you checked if the same power BI user you are using with PBI Desktop, and PBI Enterprise gateway has installed PBI personal gateway on some other machine, and personal gateway is still running from that machine?

Answer (score 0):

For Enterprise Gateway, you may not get option of scheduling refresh. Try Uninstalling personal gateway.